# Can I customize a form to generate multiple rows from a single form submission with multiple lines?

Tags: forms, smartsheet-api

Our customers will sometimes make a request to return multiple different items (with different part numbers and serial numbers) in a single request. With the out of the box Smartsheet Form fields, I can easily create a form that requires the customer enter the required information, and it will of course add a new row entry for that single form submission. The problem is that if I am a customer that needs to make a request to have several items repaired, then I would have to make a new request with each item, so I would then have to refill all the field in the form (i.e. name, addresss, etc.) just to make a request for a second item. Is there a way to either customize the form so that multiple different items can be entered, and then when submitted it creates multiple row entries in the sheet with the same submitter information, or alternatively is there a way that to add a button that once the form is submitted some of the field are then automatically repopulated with their contact information reducing the redundancy?

I have tried trying to create multiple different forms/sheets and trying to link them together, but this is a very bulky method, and still does not produce the desired effect. There should be a way to script a dynamic matrix that enables the user to add more entry lines for product information if required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to customize the Smartsheet web form in the way that you've described (i.e., such that a single form submission creates multiple new rows in the sheet).

FYI, the Smartsheet Community forum is generally the best place for asking questions like yours (about out-of-the-box Smartsheet functionality) -- while Stack Overflow is generally best suited for coding/programming-related questions (e.g., "how do I do ***xyz*** with the Smartsheet Python SDK?"). Speaking of the Smartsheet Community forum, a brief search there turned up several posts asking the same question that you've asked, including these two that may be helpful:

- [Web Forms Best Practices for multiple entries](https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/6588/web-forms-best-practices-for-multiple-entries)
- [One form into multiple entries](https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/65718/one-form-into-multiple-entries)

Finally, it's worth mentioning -- if you have access to the proper skillset (HTML + some programming language) and a web server where you could host the form, it would be possible for you to create your own custom web form (with whatever functionality you require) and then use the Smartsheet API to programmatically add data to the desired sheet when the form is submitted.